# DAX NORM.S.INV returns error when trying to add a column measure

Tags: function, powerbi, dax

I'm trying to add a calculated column in Power BI modeler with DAX.
In a column X I have a probability, say 0.08 or 0.01
For that column X I'd like to add the calculation of NORM.S.INV(mytable[columnX])
I get an error:
An argument of function 'NORM.S.INV' has the wrong data type or the result is too large.

When I enter NORM.S.INV(0.08) or some other value of column X this works fine. Same table in Excel with this function works fine as well.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Check the column data type (not only the format) is numeric.
Also, wrap the function inside a ROUND() to reduce the number of decimals.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The data type I checked and the propability is not too many decimals. Even if I use: NORM.S.INV(ROUND(TableName[ColumnName]; 2)) The problem persists.

Comment: Should be ROUND(NORM.S.INV(), 2)! The issue is the result of the function NORM, not the values in the field.

Comment: Hi Seymour. I tried your suggestion (ROUND(NORM.S.INV(RulesList[Prop]);2))
doesn't work. The error is also on the NORM.S.INV itself.